# SPSS Macro to get Stepwise AIC?

Tags: spss

How can I perform a stepwise AIC procedure using SPSS macros within the Genlin option for observing variable reduction and decreasing AIC values in a generalized model (e.g., logistic regression)?

I've tried changing the syntaxis with no good results. But in my job I can't use R or Python , I'm only allowed to use SPSS. Is there any way to get these results? I don't think manually calculate each AIC of each model with each variable is a viable way having so many variables.

EDIT1 following @eli_k advice:

```
    GENLIN SITIOINYECGLUT2DELT1 (REFERENCE=LAST) WITH DOSIS ARI DHA TOTAL
  /MODEL DOSIS ARI DHA TOTAL INTERCEPT=YES
 DISTRIBUTION=BINOMIAL LINK=LOGIT
  /CRITERIA METHOD=FISHER(1) SCALE=1 COVB=MODEL MAXITERATIONS=100 MAXSTEPHALVING=5 
    PCONVERGE=1E-006(ABSOLUTE) SINGULAR=1E-012 ANALYSISTYPE=3(WALD) CILEVEL=95 CITYPE=WALD 
    LIKELIHOOD=FULL
  /MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE
  /PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION .
```

This is the code I'm using to create a generalized lineal model, with a logistic regression on a 0/1 variable. I want to make a stepwise AIC of this model so I can eliminate all the variables that can't cross a treshhold.

When I do this, i can get the AIC of the model. But I want to get only the model with the best AIC after eliminating some variables. The process is the following:

Model with all the variable
I try to eliminate 1 variable.
I get a model -1 variable for each variable, and calculate each AIC of each model and compare with the model with all variables.
I save the best AIC model. I repeat until the model that I save is the one with best AIC.

But I can't see any way to do it.

Comment: If you edit your post to add your original syntax and a simple and clear explanation of what you are trying to get the macro to do (wouldn't hurt to add an example) we would probably be able to help you.

Comment: Done @eli-k tell me If I can add something more, and I'll do, I want to make something similar to the stepAIC function from the MASS package in R. But SPSS doesn't have any function like that.

Comment: Oh, now that I understand better what you want, I regret to tell you SPSS macro has no direct way to interact with the data and even less with analysis results in the output window. So It may be possible to do what you want with macro but only as a monstrous pile of workarounds. You could use macro to just automate running the analysis while excluding a different variable each time, but that's it. You could also use OMS to collect results for easier MANUAL selection of your preferred model.